# Xcode error "Undefined symbol: _swift_getOpaqueTypeConformance" when launch Apple Watch simulator

Tags: xcode, react-native, apple-watch

I'd like to add an Apple Watch extension to my react native app.
I created a target adapted to watchOS but when I launch a simulator with it I get this error.

[image]

I searched but didn't find anything about it. I created a new project to try, I got the same error.
Am I alone ? Do you have an idea about why this error ?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Getting the same error. Did you fix it?

Comment: I had to make react-native init on a new folder... :/

Comment: i am also running a same problem  :-(